# EntityFramework 4.1 GetValidationErrors internal exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following exception when calling System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors(), using Entity Framework Code First (4.1)

```
"An item with the same key has already been added."
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.TryCreateType(Type type, StructuralType cspaceType, EdmType& newOSpaceType)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.LoadAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData sessionData)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel.CreateObjectContext[TContext](DbConnection existingConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to identify where the issue is coming from, nor which poco entity is causing this.

Does somebody has a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is a fun one, the issue here comes from trying to re-attach an entity which is already attached to the context. This can come from a logic error or perhaps you are reusing your context without clearing the attached objects. There is a local collection on the database which you can use to see what items are currently attached to the context.

```
ctx.YourEntityCollection.Local
```